# is JSON a good solution for data transfer between client and server?

Tags: json, client, server

I am trying to understand why JSON is widely used for data transfer between client and server. I understand that it offers simple design which is easy to understand. However, on the contrary;

- A JSON string includes repeated data, e.g, incase of a table, columns names (keys) are repeated in each object . Would it not be wise to send columns as first object and rest of the object should be the data (without columns/keys information) from the table.
- Once we have a JSON object, the searching based on keys is expensive (in time) compared to indexes. Imagine a table with 20-30 column, doing this searching for each key for each object would cost a lot more time compare to directly using indexes.

There may be many more drawbacks and advantages, add here if you know one.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you want data transfer then you want a table based format.  The JSON format is not a table based format like standard databases or Excel.  This can complicate analyzing data if there is a problem because someone will usually use excel for that (sorting, filtering, formulas).  Also building test files will be more difficult because you can't simply use excel to export to JSON.

But, If you wanted to use JSON for data transfer you could basically build a JSON version of a CSV file.  You would only use arrays.

```
Columns: ["First_Name", "Last_Name"]
Rows: [
  ["Joe", "Master"],
  ["Alice", "Gooberg"]
  .... etc
]
```

Seems messy to me though.

If you wanted to use objects then you will have to embed Column names for every bit of data, which in my opinion indicates a wrong approach.